# do fibres of morphisms of Noetherian rings have finite Krull dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a morphism of Noetherian rings. Let $p \in Spec(A)$ and let $C=B \otimes \kappa(p)$ be the fibre over $p$. Is it true that $\dim C < \infty$? How can we see that?

Remark: $B \otimes \kappa(p) \cong B_S/pB_S$ where $S$ is the image of $A-p$ in $B$. Hence $C$ is not necessarily a semilocal ring and the fundamental theorem of dimension theory (i.e. that every Noetherian semilocal ring has finite dimensions) does not apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not true: we can have $\operatorname {dim} (C)=\infty.$
Indeed for any field $k=A$, Nagata has shown that there exists a Noetherian  $k$-algebra $B$ of infinite Krull dimension and this of course gives you the required example by taking $\mathfrak p=(0)$ and thus $C=B$.

Nagata's example is developed as  Exercise 9.6, page 229 of Eisenbud's [Commutative Algebra](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Fm_yPgZBucMC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 3):

No, is not! Take $A=K$ (a field) and $B$ a noetherian $K$-algebra of infinite Krull dimension (Nagata's example). Then the fibre in $(0)$ is infinite dimensional.